# How do I parse this JSON array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, bitcoin

I've been playing around a little bit with the Bitcoin API and finally have it interacting with my local bitcoind server.

Now the following code:

```
$bitcoin->listreceivedbyaccount();
```

prints the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [account] => root213
            [amount] => 1
            [confirmations] => 3
        )

)
```

How can I print or work with [account] or [amount] for example?

I'd be grateful if someone would help me out or at least push me into the right direction, because I feel lost at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't know how to use arrays, I think you should read a tutorial before making programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 *   Firstly collect the data 
 *   as an accessible variable
**/
$SomeVar = $bitcoin->listreceivedbyaccount();

/**
 *   Print the contents for just demonstration! 
 *   (Dont use print_r() in production!)
**/ 
print_r( $SomeVar );
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [account] => root213
            [amount] => 1
            [confirmations] => 3
        )

)
```

Access to 'Account'

```
echo $SomeVar[0]["account"]; //echos root213
```

Access to 'Amount'

```
echo $SomeVar[0]["amount"]; //echos 1
```

Thus from here on, you can simply reassign these again as their own variable etc =)

Comment: I feel incredibly stupid right now, but I thank you. So it's just a hierarchical type of thing?

Comment: Yea =) Although, obviously as trees get deeper, you'd need to access them via loops etc. and don't worry, we all start somewhere! Is there anything else I can help with?

Comment: Nah, I faceslapped myself when you posted that, because it's basically something I've been doing with my SQL queries: i.e. echo $row['name']; etc

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = $bitcoin->listreceivedbyaccount();

$account = $data[0]['account'];
$amount = $data[0]['amount'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrJSON = $bitcoin->listreceivedbyaccount();
foreach($arrJSON as $arr) {
    print($arr['account']);
    print($arr['amount']);           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, if you want to work with multiple values:

```
$data = $bitcoin->listreceivedbyaccount();
$count = count($data);
// Avoid errors
$amounts = array();
// Avoid errors
$confirmations = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $amounts[] = $data[$i]['amount'];
  $confirmations[] = $data[$i]['confirmations'];
}
foreach ($amounts as $amount) {
  // Do something, like:
  // print $amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option I use all the time for converting non-arrays to arrays:

```
/**
 * Convert a string, number, or object into an array.
 * Especially useful for objects such as those that
 * come from simplexml_load_file(), etc.
 *
 * @param mixed $non_array
 *   Any string, number, or object.
 *
 * @return
 *   An "arrayified" version of $non_array. At minimum,
 *   this should always return an empty array.
 */
function arrayify($non_array) {
  if (empty($non_array) && $non_array !== 0) {
    return array();
  }
  return unserialize(serialize(json_decode(json_encode((array) $non_array), 1)));
}
```

Then use it like this to extract the JSON data:

```
$data = arrayify($bitcoin->listreceivedbyaccount());
print_r($data);
```